# WebSphere Portal 6.1 theme localization

Tags: localization, properties, themes, websphere

How can a theme for a portal be localized? Suppose I wanted some text in

`IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\installedApps\lhept\wps.ear\wps.war\themes\html\<theme name>\footer.jspf`

to be different depending on locale.

It seems that I am looking for something similar to `<portal-fmt:text key="link.main.menu" bundle="nls.engine"/>"`, but I cannot locate the properties bundle file `nls.engine`, to add my own key-value pairs.

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wp.exp.doc/wps/dgn_cpinf.html seems to provide the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 6.1, properties are located in `..\WebSphere\PortalServer\ui\wp.ui\shared\app\wp.ui.jar` file.

When one wants to change the translations or add additional keys:

- the appropriate `.properties` file should be extracted to or
- a new `.properties` file should be created in

`..\WebSphere\PortalServer\shared\app\nls` directory (which is originally empty). The desired key-value pairs are entered in the extracted or newly-created `.properties` file.

Finally, the portal server must be restarted.